# Como insertar en una tabla relacionada

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php
## Título ##
if ($_POST) {
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
    $identidad = $_POST['identidad'];
    $edad = $_POST['edad'];
    $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
    $hijos = $_POST['hijos'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
     $municipios = $_POST['municipios'];//*este es un select de otra tabla municipios que me muestra todos los municipios *//
```

$ultimovalor=$municipios;//*aqui obtengo el valor del select para poderlo insertar para que tenga el mismo id que persona *//

```
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "persona_municipio");
    $ultimovalor=mysqli_insert_id($conexion);

    if ($conexion->connect_error) {
        echo('Se produjo un error al intentar realizar la conexión');
    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO persona(nombre,apellido,identidad,edad,sexo,hijos,telefono,id_municipio)
        VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido','$identidad','$edad','$sexo','$hijos','$telefono','$ultimovalor')";

        if ($conexion->query($query) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $conexion->error;
        }
        $conexion->close();
    };    
};
?>
```

Error:

> INSERT INTO
>   persona(nombre,apellido,identidad,edad,sexo,hijos,telefono,id_municipio)
>   VALUES ('juan','veliz','1517199600702','22','m','3','96453034','0')
>   Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (persona_municipio.persona, CONSTRAINT persona_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY
>   (id_municipio) REFERENCES municipio (id_municipio) ON DELETE CASCADE
>   ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: este es el error que me tira :Error: INSERT INTO persona(nombre,apellido,identidad,edad,sexo,hijos,telefono,id_municipio) VALUES ('juan','veliz','1517199600702','22','m','3','96453034','0')
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`persona_municipio`.`persona`, CONSTRAINT `persona_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_municipio`) REFERENCES `municipio` (`id_municipio`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: Creo que falta información acerca de la estructura de las tablas pero podria ser que estes intentando añadir en la columna "id_municipio" de la tabla "persona" un valor que no existe en la tabla municipio. ¿Hay algun municipio con "id_municipio" igual a 0 ?

Comment: tengo una tabla que se llama municipio  y otra persona. quiero añadir una persona a un municipio pero no se como traer el valor del municipio para que  se pueda insertar en la tabla de persona lo unico que me falta es el id de los municipios pero no se como obtenerlos

Comment: me diste una idea gracias ya lo resolví

Comment: Si puedes publica la solución de tu problema así otra gente en la misma situación quizá también encuentre la solución. ¿El problema era que no existia un municipio con id_municipio igual a 0?

Comment: si lo que me faltaba era obtener el valor del id_municipio para que se me pudiera insertar en la tabla persona para que estuviera bien relacionada una vez obtuve el valor con un select que me mostraba todos los municipios solo la guarde en una variable que se llama ultimo valor la cual inserte al final

Answer (score 1):

Una de las causas mas comunes cuando se obtiene un error en Mysql del tipo:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Es cuando se trata de hacer un insert/update en una tabla que contiene una  columna que es clave foránea y que no se le asigna un valor válido , como por ejemplo en este caso , un valor que no existe en la columna a la que referencia (municipio.id_municipio).

En este caso se trataba de hacer:

```
INSERT INTO persona 
(nombre,apellido,identidad,edad,sexo,hijos,telefono,id_municipio) 
VALUES ('juan','veliz','1517199600702','22','m','3','96453034','0');
```

Si nos fijamos se está tratando de añadir 0 en la columna persona.id_municipio (clave foranea) , lo cual no es posible ya que en la tabla municipio no había ningún municipio con id_municipio igual a 0.

En este caso se solucionó obteniendo un valor correcto  para la columna id_municipio para posteriormente poder ejecutar la sentencia sql correctamente.